# What does the "g" stand for in Ruby's "gsub" and in Vim's substitution command?

Tags: ruby, regex, vim

Both Ruby and Vim use "g" with substitution commands to mean "all occurrences." **What does the "g" stand for?**

Specifically, in Ruby, the [String class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html) has two "sub" commands: `sub` will replace only the first occurrence, and `gsub` will replace all occurrences. For example:

```
string = "One potato, two potato, three potato, four."
string.sub('potato','banana') # => "One banana, two potato, three potato, four."
string.gsub('potato','banana') # => "One banana, two banana, three banana, four."
```

Similarly, in Vim, `:%s/foo/bar` will look through the whole file (which is what `%` means) and substitute one occurrence per line, but `:%s/foo/bar/g` will do all occurrences on each line.

My guess would be that in both cases, "g" means "greedy," because both the Ruby commands and the Vim command accept a regular expression, but my understanding of greedy matching is "match the longest possible substring meeting these criteria," not "match as many substrings as possible." (See "[Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)")

Comment: Maybe it means "global"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I remember correctly it means `global`, which [this Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) seems to confirm:

> The g flag means global – each
>   occurrence in the line is changed,
>   rather than just the first.

Comment: Nice find. I had done `:help :s` and looked down at the flags section, but it just said "Replace all occurrences in the line."

Comment: My question was vague about whether the answer should be for Vim or Ruby or both, but since you were the only person to give citation so far, I'm accepting this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think it stands for "global".

Following vim's help from `:help :s` to `:help s_flags` to `:help gdefault` says:

```
'gdefault' 'gd'         boolean (default off)
                        global
```

Comment: I think so too. Googling for `ruby "global substitition"` got me a citation: Google Books found Hal Fulton making this assertion in The Ruby Way.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the "g" stood for global, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `g` flag in regex == `gloabl` replacement.  Probably the same implication for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I think, "g" is stand for "**greedy**". It is more close with regular expressions foundations.