# String replacement in R using gsub

Tags: r, regex

I have a variable `a = "ver version"` and `v = "version"`. Now I want to replace `'ver'` with `'version'` using `gsub`.

Using `gsub(v, "version", a)` output is `"version versionsion"` I want it to be `"version version"`. To replace exact string, I use `"\\bpattern\\b"`

```
gsub("\\bv\\b","version,a)
```

It says unexpected input. Can someone suggest the correct syntax for the same?

Comment: If you are using `v`, then use `paste` i.e. `gsub(paste0("\b", v, "\b"), "version", a)` or just `gsub("\\bver\\b", "version", a)` (assuming that there could be multiple cases of 'ver')

Comment: thank you akrun, worked fine

Comment: @ZheyuanLi not the most authoritative source, but you're not the only one to think [g stands for global](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6124591/903061).

Comment: Thank you! It had never occurred to me before and from now on I will always remember the difference between `sub` and `gsub` without having to look at the documentation.